# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component StandardEngine.StandardHost.StandardContext

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I see this error when I try to run my application on the Server:

```
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/GestioneAuleCorsi]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/GestioneAuleCorsi]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@368d1ac]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5057)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@6e54a425]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:699)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:716)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:419)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(IOUtils.java:65)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(JarFile.java:425)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:193)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
    ... 13 more
```

and also I see the following in Eclipse:

```
GRAVE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:305)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:831)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Before it was working, then I imported a different project and so Maven downloaded other versions of dependencies/Jar. This I think could have downloaded conflicting things.

Comment: Are you using any zip file in your program? This could be a problem with one of the jar file in your application. Tomcat is complaining about unreadable jar file on the classpath.

Comment: try clearing your local m2 repository and build your artifact again.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same problem.But I just added a jar file named commons-logging and it worked.